# How to use ellipsis (`...`) when defining functions in R

Tags: r, function, plot, ellipsis

I knew `...` permits user to input the parameters arbitrary. However, I have some further questions about how to use `...` when defining a new function in R. Here are the examples:

```
data <- 1:10

PLOT <- function(data, ...){
par(mfrow = c(1, 2)

# Figure1
plot(data, ...)

# Figure2
plot(data, ...)
}

PLOT(data = data, col = "red")
```

The outcome is figure1 with red points and figure2 with red points. Here are the following questions:

1. I would like to adjust figure1 and figure2 separately (e.g., figure1 in red points and figure2 in blue points), How can I do?
2. I have many arguments to adjust, some of them adjust only figure1, some of them adjust only figure2, and some of them adjust both (e.g., figure1 in red with dash line; figure2 in blue with solid line; and both figures should have title of "Testing" and no x axis), how can I do?

I have googled and test different ways to code. However, I can't figure out how to do. I expect to see an answer with an explanation of the usage of `...` and example codes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try passing vector like this :
`PLOT(data = data, col = c("red", "blue"), lty = c(2, 1))`. This will create Figure 1 with red dashed line and Figure 2 with blue solid line

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan I dont believe that's true, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4K9u.png) when I run your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dots to pass multiple arguments with the same name to different function calls. The normal way round this is to pass a `list` with the additional arguments for each function call:

```r
data <- 1:10

PLOT <- function(data, fig1_args = list(), fig2_args = list()) {
  par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
      
      # Figure1
      do.call("plot", c(list(x = data), fig1_args))
      
      # Figure2
      do.call("plot", c(list(x = data), fig2_args))
}

PLOT(data = data, fig1_args = list(col = "red"), fig2_args = list(col = "blue"))
```

[image]

The alternative if you only need to be able to change one or two aspects of each plot is to have a specific copy of each parameter:

```r
PLOT <- function(data, col1 = 'black', col2 = 'black') {
  par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
      
      # Figure1
      plot(data, col = col1)
      
      # Figure2
      plot(data, col = col2)
}

PLOT(data = data, col1 = 'red', col2 = 'blue')
```

[image]

This doesn't scale well if you want to preserve the ability to change many different features of each plot.

Comment: do.call() here can be explained as: "do the plot() function with parameters c(list(x = data), fig1_args)". Am I right?

Comment: @HsunHungChu exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain it in the following way. Say there is a function:

```
foo_inner <- function(par2 = "B", par3 = "C"){
  print(par2)
  print(par3)
}
```

It may be called:

```
foo_inner(par2 = "My2")
[1] "My2"
[1] "C"
```

If we have an outer function that is calling inner one from inside itself it can pass parameters to the inner function using `...`. See this code:

```
foo_outer <- function(par1 = "A",...){
  print(par1)
  foo_inner(...)
}
```

When we call and pass a parameter that `foo_outer()` does not explicitly have in its declaration it passes them to the function called from inside the code of the outer function:

```
foo_outer(par1 = "My1", par2 = "My2")
```

It returns:

```
[1] "My1"
[1] "My2"
[1] "C"
```

So concerning your question. You may pass any parameters of `plot()` calling `PLOT()`. Ellipse will not differentiate the calls of `plot()` and will pass forward these parameters to each `plot()` call.

**APPENDED**

You can also get access to the `...` parameters from outer function. See for instance:

```
foo_outer <- function(par1 = "A",...){
  print(par1)
  foo_inner(...)
  ... |> c() |> print()
}
```

`foo_outer(par1 = "My1", par2 = "My2")` will return:

```
[1] "My1"
[1] "My2"
[1] "C"
 par2 
"My2"
```

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't allow _arbitrary_ arguments to be passed.  For something like `plot`, where there are dozens of possible parameters, having two versions of each isn't really feasible (or at least is bad design). Having said that, this is probably the way to go if you only need to be able to change a couple of parameters, like the color and shape of the dots.

Comment: @AllanCameron `par2` is an arbitary parameter as it is not listed in `foo_outer()` declaration isn't it? So you may pass dosens of `plot()` parameters (and parameters of its 'daughter' functions) using `PLOT()` wrapper call without having to list them in `PLOT()` declaration.

Comment: @AllanCameron See also APPENDED section of my answer

Comment: Sure - I guess I missed the point that you are showing why `...` _can't_ be used to pass multiple versions of the same parameter to two calls to the same inner function,  rather than how you would go about achieving the desired goal.

Comment: @AllanCameron I was simply trying to answer the question verbatim that sounds as "How to use ellipsis ('...') when defining functions in R" and it seems that our answers append each other as you are explaining how to pass variable parameters to internal functions (not using ellipse) and me how to use ellipse in function declaration. Cheers!